# Parsing xml files with &lt; and &gt;

Tags: java, xml

I am parsing xml files to query some fields with Lucene. But I have a problem with `&lt;` and `&gt;` . I know that invalids characters at xml are "&", "<", ">".

So my question is: how to represent < and > in a xml file?

Example of xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<iniciativa_completa>
  <legislatura>NSA</legislatura>
  <numero_diario>3, 123, 257-65</numero_diario>
  <parrafo> While the individual main effects were modest, each yielding OR &lt; 1.6, the effects were cumulative, with some combinations reaching OR = 12.6 (95% CI: 5.9-26.8).</parrafo>
</iniciativa_completa>
```

Then, in my java code:

```
String resumen = "";
XMLInputFactory xmlInputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
XMLEventReader xmlEventReader = xmlInputFactory.createXMLEventReader(new FileInputStream(fileName));
xmlEventReader.nextEvent();

while (xmlEventReader.hasNext()) {
     XMLEvent xmlEvent = xmlEventReader.nextEvent();

     if (xmlEvent.isStartElement()) {
         StartElement startElement = xmlEvent.asStartElement();

        if (startElement.getName().getLocalPart().equals("parrafo")) {
           xmlEvent = xmlEventReader.nextEvent();
           resumen = xmlEvent.toString();                            
        }
     }
}
```

When I parse it, resumen is equal to "While the individual main effects were modest, each yielding OR".

I have tried also `&#60;` and `&#62;`

Thanks!

Comment: `&lt;` and `&gt;` are perfectly fine. What issue are you facing with them?

Comment: For example here:
"While the individual main effects were modest, each yielding OR &lt; 1.6, the effects were cumulative"

I get this: "While the individual main effects were modest, each yielding OR" when I parse it.

Comment: [Edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46400174/edit) and include all the details, including an example that demonstrates the issue (XML code + Java code).

Comment: I have added some code.

Comment: Please post a code that compiles. `abstract` is a reserved word in java, your code won't compile.

Comment: @César Something I find little strange is `abstract` as a string name. It is already a reserved Java keyword. Though it has nothing to do with the solution, it isn't a good practice. :)

Comment: @procrastinator it was an example. In my real code the name is "resumen".

Comment: Yes. It was an example. I have edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed the error. After create the XMLInputFactory, I set the following property:

```
 xmlInputFactory.setProperty(IS_COALESCING,true);
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLInputFactory.html

Thanks everyone.